slide up table row each after one
currently I'm working on a grid with group rows (on top). If the user clicks on the first cell of the group row (a - sign) the details rows should slide up with animation. I found this answer, and modified the relevant code like this:
$(`[kendogridlogicalrow][calcrowname=${calcRowName}]`)
        .animate({ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }, 500)
        .wrapInner('<div />')
        .children()
        .slideUp(500, function () {
          $(this).closest('tr').hide();
        });

With this all the td elements get wrapped in a div inside a row. I get the 'almost' desired result (there is a slide effect), but the detail rows don't shrink like in the linked example. See this demo.
How can I achieve, that with the slide effect starting from the last detail row the rows are shrinked and then disapper? Should I maybe use each and delay?
EDIT: here is a sample:


$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('[detailrow]')
        .animate({ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }, 500)
        .wrapInner('<div />')
        .children()
        .slideUp(500, function () {
          $(this).closest('tr').hide();
        });
});
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr th, tr td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

tr.group-row {
  font-weight: bold;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group-row'>
    <td>
      group row
      <button id="btn" type="button">collapse</button>
    </td>
    <td>group row</td>
    <td>group row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr detailrow>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr detailrow>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr detailrow>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr detailrow>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='group-row'>
    <td>
      group row
      <button type="button">collapse</button>
    </td>
    <td>group row</td>
    <td>group row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>



EDIT 2:
Finally I managed it. I inserted a div below the group row and wrapped to this div the detail rows. This has messed up the layout of course, so I had to set the height of this div to the total height of the detail rows and the width to the total width of the table columns, and also I have to set the width of the td elements of the detail rows to the original width. With this I got back the table layout. And finally I had to animate this div.
Here is an example: https://gifyu.com/image/SD6d3

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

https://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/z2fwdLdu/30/

Please post a minimal reproducible example.  so that we can help you. or check the above fiddle having smooth slide effect

The [kendogridlogicalrow] selector implies the use of kendo.  Which means it's likely not a plain <table><tbody><tr>

I have already checked it's markup, and yes, there are some other elements too, but basically it is a 'simple' table with the known elements.

Is your problem just that you want it to apply to all buttons? Your question is not 100% clear to me.
